# Columns are not working in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <img class="title-logo" src="logo.jpg" height=100 width:100 alt="mainlogo">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
       <h1 class="titel-super text-thin">Live Aider</h1>
       <h4>A Plateform where you can interact</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want a row with two column with above code but its not working with bootstrap.

Comment: what is not working?? have you included bootstrap js and css file

Comment: width:100 may be a typo...

Comment: Yes I have @AtalShrivastava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Test you code, Its working well.
I just copy paste your code working perfect with both columns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <img class="title-logo" src="http://www.ikoreadaily.co.kr/news/photo/201512/217773_113769_5446.JPG" height=100 width:100 alt="mainlogo">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
       <h1 class="titel-super text-thin">Live Aider</h1>
       <h4>A Plateform where you can interact</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

You must have check with browser width and give full html code you have used right now. if you need small screen with both columns side by side then use "`col-xs-*`".

Comment: my pleasure @Akram

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping everything in a container div. Also, you had a typo in your img width attribute.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <img class="title-logo" src="logo.jpg" height=100 width=100 alt="mainlogo">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
       <h1 class="titel-super text-thin">Live Aider</h1>
       <h4>A Plateform where you can interact</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```